Should we set the "dialect" tags as mandatory?
I was thinking that we have a tag mandarin, I'm not sure if we have tags for taiwanese and cantonese, but my point is, should we make them as mandatory for each question?
Regardless if the question refers to just one or all of them, it would be good to know what "dialect" (I know I'm using this term inappropriately, that's why the quotes) is the question referring to.

On the site so far I would assume more than 95% are about Mandarin. My preference is to not use the Mandarin tag because Mandarin is the norm, you are then just adding a piece of info that is extraneous, a meta tag.
I suggest using the other tags to clarify when it is not Mandarin.

Uhm I see, you have a point. How do we suggest people to do so? I think the only way we have is do it and suggest it when possible...

@Alenanno - Good moderation comes from the community. If you have see a question that is missing tags then jump in and change it. Most people will notice the edit when they check their question for answers.

+1 I think assuming it's Mandarin unless explicitly stated otherwise is the way to go.
